# JS: Clicking on a object from array --> show more info

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a array of objects that I included into my HTML. I have to be able to click on the object and show all the info of the product (id, title, book, price, calories, ...).

What is the best way to do this?

Snippet:

Thanks in advance!

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadMeals);

const meals = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Strawberry Salad with Poppy Seed Dressing',
        img: 'Strawberry-Salad-with-Poppy-Seed-Dressing.jpg',
        book: 1,
        calories: 298,
        servings: 3,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 15,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Cashew Turkey Salad Sandwiches',
        img: 'turkey-sandwich.jpg',
        book: 2,
        calories: 198,
        servings: 2,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 9,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10
    }
];


function loadMeals() {
    let i = 0;
    let id = 1;
    let fillMealList = document.querySelector("#fillMealList");
    for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
        let item = meals.find(item => item.id === id);
        fillMealList.innerHTML +=
            "<article>"+
            "<h3>" + item.title + "</h3>"+
            "<figure>"+
            "<img src='images/" + item.img + "'" +">" +
            "<figcaption>"+
            "Meal by: " +"<span>" + item.cook + "</span>" +
            "</figcaption>" +
            "</figure>"+
            "<div class='info'>"+
            "<p>€ <span>" + item.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
            "<a href='#' class='addToCart'>Order</a>"+
            "</div>"+
            "</article>";
        id++;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="mealList">
            <div class="flexcontainer" id="fillMealList"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is that something that you'd like to happen when the user clicks 'Order'?

Comment: No it's something I want to happen when the user clicks on the object it self

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the index of the clicked article and get the item from the array with that index.

You can try the following way:

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadMeals);

const meals = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Strawberry Salad with Poppy Seed Dressing',
        img: 'Strawberry-Salad-with-Poppy-Seed-Dressing.jpg',
        book: 1,
        calories: 298,
        servings: 3,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 15,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Cashew Turkey Salad Sandwiches',
        img: 'turkey-sandwich.jpg',
        book: 2,
        calories: 198,
        servings: 2,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 9,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10
    }
];


function loadMeals() {
    let i = 0;
    let id = 1;
    let fillMealList = document.querySelector("#fillMealList");
    for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
        let item = meals.find(item => item.id === id);
        fillMealList.innerHTML +=
            "<article class='objectP'>"+
            "<h3>" + item.title + "</h3>"+
            "<figure>"+
            "<img src='images/" + item.img + "'" +">" +
            "<figcaption>"+
            "Meal by: " +"<span>" + item.cook + "</span>" +
            "</figcaption>" +
            "</figure>"+
            "<div class='info'>"+
            "<p>€ <span>" + item.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
            "<a href='#' class='addToCart'>Order</a>"+
            "</div>"+
            "</article>";
        id++;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.objectP').forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('fillMealList').children );
      var idx = nodes.indexOf(this);
      console.clear(); // clears the console
      console.log(meals[idx])
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="mealList">
  <div class="flexcontainer" id="fillMealList"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can attach an `onClick` listener to your button which passes `id` as the parameter and then you can easily get the data from the `id`.

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadMeals);

const meals = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Strawberry Salad with Poppy Seed Dressing',
        img: 'Strawberry-Salad-with-Poppy-Seed-Dressing.jpg',
        book: 1,
        calories: 298,
        servings: 3,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 15,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Cashew Turkey Salad Sandwiches',
        img: 'turkey-sandwich.jpg',
        book: 2,
        calories: 198,
        servings: 2,
        type: 'lunch',
        price: 9,
        cook: 'Jenny Jefferson',
        quantity: 10
    }
];

function getInfo(id){ 
meals.forEach( meal => {
  if(meal.id === id){ console.log(meal) }
} )
}

function loadMeals() {
    let i = 0;
    let id = 1;
    let fillMealList = document.querySelector("#fillMealList");
    for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
        let item = meals.find(item => item.id === id);
        fillMealList.innerHTML +=
            "<article id={`item.id`} >"+
            "<h3>" + item.title + "</h3>"+
            "<figure>"+
            "<img src='images/" + item.img + "'" +">" +
            "<figcaption>"+
            "Meal by: " +"<span>" + item.cook + "</span>" +
            "</figcaption>" +
            "</figure>"+
            "<div class='info'>"+
            "<p>€ <span>" + item.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
            "<a href='#' onclick='getInfo(" + item.id + ")' class='addToCart'>Order</a>"+
            "</div>"+
            "</article>";
        id++;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="mealList">
            <div class="flexcontainer" id="fillMealList"></div>
            </div>
```